# ASP.net MVC 4 Creating new controller issue 'unable to retrieve metadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, connection-string

I'm trying to Add new controller in my project but I got this error :

```
unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcApplication1.Models.REGION" object reference not set to instance of object.
```

And this's my connection string:

```
<`add name="EntitiesRegion" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.region.csdl|res://*/Models.region.ssdl|res://*/Models.region.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521;PASSWORD=1234;USER ID=TEST&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
```

And her's the content of **region.Context.cs** :

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class EntitiesRegion : DbContext
    {
        public EntitiesRegion()
            : base("name=EntitiesRegion")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<REGION> REGION { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also I'm using **Oracle Database** and **Entity Framework 5**. Any help please.

Comment: please send your cshtml file.